# php - Is php caching classes before creation?

Tags: symfony, caching, console-application

## Background Information:

I'm using [Symfony Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) to write a console application that is wrapped into a [`Shell`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Console/Shell.html) object. I wrote a command named `console:reload` that empties the array of commands from the `Application` object, and re-adds commands classes listed under certain directory.

This command is run when the shell starts, so, the `Application` is loaded with the available commands. The classes being loaded are located in a special directory and should follow a simple name rule: `<CommandName>Command.php`:

```
// Inside ReloadCommand->execute() method...
$pamperoApp = $this->getApplication();
$pamperoApp->clearCommands();
$namespace = "pampero\\cli\\modules";
foreach(glob(MODULES_DIR . "/*/*Command.php") as $command) {
    $class = str_replace(".php", "", $namespace . "\\" . basename(dirname($command)) . "\\" . basename($command));
    $this->getApplication()->add(new $class);
 }
```

The autoload provided by Symfony (Composer?) `ClassLoader` is used:

```
// Main entry point...
loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->set('pampero', __DIR__ . '/../..');
```

I read the code from `ClassLoader` class and what it does is to store file name path, so no object caching there.

## Here's the problem:

I launch the app: `php packages.php`. The shell appears after `ReloadCommand` command being executed. A list of available and loaded commands are ready to be used.

If I create a new file, let's say: `ExampleCommand.php`, and then I type: `console:reload`, the new command will indeed be added. Now, If I modify the code inside `ExampleCommand.php` and run `console:reload` again, the changes made to the class won't take effect.

But that's not all. If I remove the example file, call `console:reload`, create the file again and run: `console:reload` the command will be added.

## Reading:

I have read APC related things, and before creating new classes I have done things like:

```
// Prior adding commands in ReloadCommand
apc_clear_cache();
apc_clear_cache('user');
apc_clear_cache('opcode');
```

Without luck. I've also run `apc.php` and enabled/disabled `apc.enable_cli` option. None of those things creates the object represented by the modified file.

So my hints and clues about the problems turns to be classes caching when a file/class is found. But how to avoid that for this special case? I don't want to restart the shell if some extra funcionality is added through classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem resides that when a file is included, changes to the file won't be reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I found a solution.

Ok, clues were fine. The problem was that PHP including a file binds the symbols for later use while parsing the file.

So, I needed some kind of instrospection. After reading/googling/searching for all night, finally I've ended up finding [Runkit](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit).

[Runkit documentation](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) can be found here. I know that is not the best thing you can do with your code design. But for my project needs, the truth is that [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) was needed.

Here is the modified code using `Runkit`:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // Gets a reference to the console application and removes all commands
    $pamperoApp = $this->getApplication();
    $pamperoApp->clearCommands();
    // Adds default commands and add this command
    $pamperoApp->addCommands($pamperoApp->getDefaultCommands());
    $pamperoApp->add($this);

    $namespace = "pampero\\cli\\modules";

    foreach(glob(MODULES_DIR . "/*/*Command.php") as $filename) {
            $className = str_replace(".php", "", $namespace . "\\" . basename(dirname($filename)) . "\\" . basename($filename));
            // Do not add this command again. This command shouldn't be modified on-the-fly
            if (get_class($this) !== $className) {
                    $class = new $className();
                    // Redefines the class definition
                    runkit_import($filename, RUNKIT_IMPORT_CLASSES | RUNKIT_OVERRIDE_OBJECTS | RUNKIT_IMPORT_OVERRIDE);
                    $pamperoApp->add($class);
            }
    }
}
```